# Missing Hardrive icon in Finder, OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 MacBook Air

Tags: macos, mac, finder, icon

I purchased a Mid 2013 MacBook Air with OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 and I am unable to locate the hardrive icon in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Finder -> Preferences -> Sidebar and make sure "Hard disks" is selected.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you meant on the Desktop rather than the sidebar...
Finder > Preferences > General >

[image]